# how do i grab orderId from this array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can i enter this array and grab the orderId ?

```
array(1) { 

["data"] => array(1) {

["orderId"] => int(100)
  }

}
```

ive tried to

```
print_r ["array"]["1"]["array"]["1"]["orderId"];
```

ive tried

```
foreach($array as $data)
echo ["data"]["orderId"] ;
```

Also note, i am receiving this json as a webhook and decoding it to php object with json_decode($json, true);

What am i missing? Should be simple but i cannot get it.

Thanks

Comment: what is the name of the variable containing the array?

Comment: Try this -> `$array[0]["data"][0]["orderId"]`

Comment: @LioraHaydont, I guess the variable name is `$array`, as this variable is used in `foreach` loop. I am not sure whether this is a reserved keyword or not.

Comment: I would recommend that you [read the manual about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). It explains how you create arrays, read and set values.

Comment: a hint: the '1' you see here `array(1) { ` is _not_ the index, but the size (number of items in the array). And the 'array' is a description of the datatype, not a name. (because you tried `["array"]["1"]`). So `$array['data']['orderId']` would be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the JSON data you're receiving is in the `$array` variable:

```
$orderId = $array["data"]["orderId"];
```

Explanation:

- First you grab the "data" property from the array
- That *data* property contains another array which has its own properties.
- From that array, you can grab the "orderId" property.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: you're sure about the indexes (`[0]`)?

Comment: Not sure, now that you mention it, the counts in the print_r statement could point to the amount of properties on the objects. In this case it should be:

`$array["data"]["orderId"]`

Comment: yup, that's it. but what we see (on the top) is a var_dump. Keys are always in `[]` - for print_r and for var_dump

Comment: @Jeff I just edited my answer :) Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

If your array is named `$that`, use `$that['data']['orderId'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this    $array["data"]["orderId"] `